# Click on Imageview and open fullscreen-image in new Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a MainActivity with 4 imageviews placed in 4 different card views.
What I would like to is, when clicking on one of these cardviews/imageviews it shows the image in fullscreen in a new activity.

I guess I could create 4 new activities and place a fullscreen imageview in each one of those, referencing to the selected image in MainActivity. But this approach does not seem so smooth.

I would prefer one "imageActivity" and then pass the selected imageview. Could this be done with passing the parameter for the resource id?

Comment: You can use `Bundle options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, view, Contract.SHARED_IMAGE_ELEMENT_NAME).toBundle();
ActivityCompat.startActivity(this,intent, options);`

Comment: And you can look at [https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations/blob/master/README.md](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

There can be a good solution than what I am going to offer but as even I'm learning and if it's just about 4 cardviews, I would've done the following.

Create a public static variable in MainActivity
`public static Drawable resId;`

set onClickListener for every `Imageview` like this.

```
ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        resId = R.drawable.image1;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,your_fullscreen_activity_name.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        
    }
});
ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);
image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        resId = R.drawable.image2;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,your_fullscreen_activity_name.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        
    }
});
ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image3);
image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        resId = R.drawable.image3;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,your_fullscreen_activity_name.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        
    }
});
ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image4);
image4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        resId = R.drawable.image4;
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,your_fullscreen_activity_name.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        
    }
});
```

or on the cardviews, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081787/onclicklistener-for-cardview) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142329/how-to-add-onclicklistner-to-cardview).
Create a fullscreenactivity and put its name in those intents.
Then in the java file of this fullscreenactivity, get the reference of layout/imageview and do this.

```
    ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(R.id.fullscreenLayout);
    viewGroup.setBackgroundDrawable(MainActivity.resId);
```

**OR**

```
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreenImageview); 
    imageView .setBackgroundDrawable(MainActivity.resId);
```

You can use either the `imageView` or the `viewGroup`.

And yes, Don't forget to add id of layout in XML file of fullscreenactivity or create a imagview with size same as parent layout.
If anything is confusing/not helpful, I'll help.

Comment: Why not just set `Home.flag` to the drawable resource?

Comment: Also, the static variable really isn't needed. Pass the integer via that Intent

Comment: @cricket_007  yes, one can use putExtra with intent and also one can create a Drawable variable in Home/Mainactivity and pass it but nothing wrong here too. More I'll get experience, better I'll try to answer. Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try to improve.